# NSArray objectAtIndex index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, ios8

I'm working on someone else's app and and I'm getting this error:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 
 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Xcode points to this line:

```
 NSDictionary *geo = [response[0] objectForKey:@"geometry"];
```

Here's the full method:

```
- (void)loadLatLong {

indx ++;
if (indx == [datalist count]) {
    [self showMarker];
//        self.alertView.hidden = true;
//        [self setThreeQuarters];
    [self.progressbar setProgress:1.0 animated:YES];
    return;
}
PointClass *pt = datalist[indx];
NSString *stPt = [pt.Location stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *str = [stPt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAoSBH8mBmeVp2HVx6vJrkTvl3bjRFiWag",str];

NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
[manager GET:[urlString absoluteString ]parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSArray *response = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
    NSDictionary *geo = [response[0] objectForKey:@"geometry"];
    NSDictionary *location = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];

    pt.lat = [[location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    pt.lng = [[location objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
    datalist[indx] = pt;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%d \n"], indx);
    [self loadLatLong];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

  }];
}
```

Can't figure out where to change the code.

UPDATE:
I want to add that it only crashes sometimes and sometimes it loads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code makes an assumption that `response` array always has at least one element. This breaks when the array is empty, so you need to add code to check for it:

```
NSArray *response = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
if (response.count == 0) {
    // Continue loading more data:
    [self loadLatLong];
    return;
}
NSDictionary *geo = [response[0] objectForKey:@"geometry"];
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well, the app doesn't crash, but stops downloading objects at number 71. I think there are 85 objects in the array. http://www.screencast.com/t/i1bMk3EW

Comment: @Paul Create a new question since there is now a new problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OK, I see. It stops on 71 because there isn't an element.It's zero, everything else is 1. I think it's downloading this from the Google server. http://www.screencast.com/t/kYr9OU0S2

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Is this a server issue?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The app stopped crashing, but stops on record 70. Is this a sever problem? I checked the server and everything is populated.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight By recursively, do you mean the method is calling itself? Yeah, that doesn't seem right. I'm not really sure how it should be done. I didn't write it, but trying to fix it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ok, I will ask another question. But you are suggesting a GCD queue? Which part of the method should I wrap the GCD queue? Thanks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight   So I wrap GCD like this?  https://gist.github.com/lumierephoto/7344066ffb3eca39fb23

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I tried it, but it halts on the first record. It won't download anything.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I did it like this: https://gist.github.com/lumierephoto/7344066ffb3eca39fb23

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Do you mean like this? https://gist.github.com/lumierephoto/7344066ffb3eca39fb23  I tried that already, but still stopped on the first record.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That was it! You're a genius man! Update your answer and will give you credit.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Also, will give you credit on the other question I created if you add an answer.

Comment: @Paul My edit already has the update. I'll answer your other question with an explanation of why this works, and why I was wrong suggesting that the invocation is recursive.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Awesome. I'd love to hear your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is crashed because the `response` don't have any object. You should check it before calling `response[0]`. Something like this `if ([response count] == 0) return;`

Comment: The app just stops downloading objects at number 71 after putting in your code. I think there are 85 objects in the array. screencast.com/t/i1bMk3EW