# Google Directions API

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-api, google-directions-api

Trying to use google directions api in my simple project. 
But work return me fail.
What's wrong with it?
Example of code from google on [github](https://github.com/ManoMarks/demos/tree/master/DirectionsAPIAsync)

In file MDDirectionService.m we have method "setDirectionsQuery"
but today query google api have another structure.
I change query to use API KEY but code not working

```
static NSString *kMDDirectionsURL = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";

    - (void)setDirectionsQuery:(NSDictionary *)query
                  withSelector:(SEL)selector
                  withDelegate:(id)delegate
    {
        NSArray *waypoints = query[@"waypoints"];
        NSString *origin = waypoints[0];
        int waypointCount = [waypoints count];
        int destinationPos = waypointCount - 1;
        NSString *destination = waypoints[destinationPos];
        NSString *key = @"my key";
        NSMutableString *url =
        [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@&origin=%@&destination=%@&key=%@",
         kMDDirectionsURL, origin, destination, key];
        if(waypointCount > 2) {
            [url appendString:@"&waypoints=optimize:true"];
            int wpCount = waypointCount-2;
            for(int i=1;i<wpCount;i++){
                [url appendString: @"|"];
                [url appendString:[waypoints objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
        url = [[url
                stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] mutableCopy];
        _directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        [self retrieveDirections:selector
                    withDelegate:delegate];
    }
```

in ViewController.m file method calls in func "didTapAtCoordinate"

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:
                (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {

  CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                    coordinate.latitude,
                                    coordinate.longitude);
  GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
  marker.map = mapView_;
  [waypoints_ addObject:marker];
  NSString *positionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",
                              coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
    [waypointStrings_ addObject:positionString];
  if([waypoints_ count]>1){
    NSString *sensor = @"false";
    NSArray *parameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sensor, waypointStrings_,
                           nil];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sensor", @"waypoints", nil];
    NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:parameters
                                                      forKeys:keys];
    MDDirectionService *mds=[[MDDirectionService alloc] init];
    SEL selector = @selector(addDirections:);
    [mds setDirectionsQuery:query
               withSelector:selector
               withDelegate:self];
  }
}
```

How i need change this code, for correctly work

```
NSDictionary *query = @{ @"sensor" : @"false", @"waypoints" : self.waypointStrings };
        DirectionService *mds = [[DirectionService alloc] init];
        SEL selector = @selector(addDirections:);
        [mds setDirectionsQuery:query
                   withSelector:selector
                   withDelegate:self];
```

When i try use it have the error in this code:

```
-(void)addDirections:(NSDictionary *)json
{

    NSDictionary *routes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"][0];
    NSDictionary *route = [routes objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
    NSString *overview_route = [route objectForKey:@"points"];
    GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:overview_route];
    GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    polyline.map = self.mapView;
}
```

With message error like:

you tapped at -73.254689, 40.840717

you tapped at -73.253745, 40.837211

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
 '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822576/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsrangeexception-reason-n), you are getting the error **NSRangeException** because you are trying to access array [0] for an NSArray that is empty.

This can be caused by an [off by one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622530/nsarray-objectatindex-index-0-beyond-bounds-for-empty-array) might also help.

> The code makes an assumption that `response` array always has at least
>   one element. This breaks when the array is empty, so you need to add
>   code to check for it:
>
> ```
> NSArray *response = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
> if (response.count == 0) {
>     // Continue loading more data:
>     [self loadLatLong];
>     return;
> }
> NSDictionary *geo = [response[0] objectForKey:@"geometry"];
> ```
>
> It  crashed because the `response` don't have any object. You should check it before calling `response[0]`. Something like this `if ([response count] == 0) return;`.